# Selecting rows of the highest value For Each of another column value?

Tags: mysql

I have been looking but the answers I find are all about the MAX in a given column for an entire table.

I need to select the highest(up to 4) for each of another column's values into a second table.
It would be easiest to represent as something simple...

```
Scores_Stored
ID, UserID, Score, date, etc
1,   4,      325,   ....
2,   5,      276,   ....
3,   5,      341,   ....
```

In this example I would need the highest "score" valued rows for each UserID.

I have tried various ways of joining the table with itself using aliases but I keep getting stuck with either something that sorts the highest 5 overall, or keeps sorting the same selection.

I should try again after some sleep, but I would really like to finish this.

Comment: Do you need upto 4 highscores per UserID or 4 highscores for all users? And what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(Score) AS Score
FROM Scores_Stored
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY Score
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: I have tried this, and the more useful (to my purposes) ..
SELECT *, MAX(Score) INTO.. 
but it doesn't work as intended.  Every use of MAX(anything) I use generates an output of the preceding columns followed by an empty one named "MAX(anything)"

Comment: You could add WHERE Score IS NOT NULL. But it should always return the maximum score. How do you verify it is empy? Using PHP? You would need the alias (AS Score) to select it in PHP as 'Score'.

Comment: Was only using MySQL in HeidiSQL.
I switched to a terminal for the SQL - it gave a list of rows but only 5 items from a table with more than 100,000 unique "UserID" equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select max(score) as max_score,user_id from score_Stored  group by user_id;
```